# JQuery Slider - stop function - what if a user doesn't 'stop'?

Tags: jquery

I have this code which uses JQuery UI to create a slider. It calls a function when the slider is stopped (when you stop moving the slider) and creates a hidden form field with the value contained in the slider (so that it can be POST'ed once the form is submitted.)

This works perfectly except for one minor bug:

If the user doesn't move the slider, `stop:` is never triggered and therefore, a hidden form field is never created.

What's the best way to fix this?

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider8" ).slider({
     orientation: "horizontal",
     range: "min",
     min: 0,
     max: 100,
     value: 50,
     stop: function(event, ui) {
        var $s1 = $('<input/>', {type: 'hidden',id:'slider8',name:'slider8', value: ui.value});
        $s1.appendTo('.form-horizontal');
     }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Change your ux logic?

Comment: why not add the hidden form field always and have it contain a default value, that way there is always a value there. Then simply overwrite the value if the user does use your slider?

Comment: Doh. Why didn't I think of that? :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

My initial suggestion was to attach the jQuery UI slider to a range input type, but jQuery UI doesn't support that - it only gets attached to divs, not input elements. My mistake.

Here's a complete jsFiddle example of what you wish to achieve. You need to create your hidden element in the create event, and update it in the change event, like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider8ui"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#slider8ui" ).slider({
     orientation: "horizontal",
     range: "min",
     min: 0,
     max: 100,
     value: 50,
     create: function( event, ui ) {
        $('<input/>', {type: 'text',id:'slider8',name:'slider8', value: 50}).appendTo('#slider8ui');
     },
     change: function(event, ui) {
        $("#slider8").val(ui.value);
     }
  });
 });
```

Here's the complete jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TdpX9/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, seems like you can't attach jQuery UI slider to an input element. I've just rewritten my reply, including a complete working example